# How installing blade template in Microframework Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-blade, lumen-5.2

I have this version:
**Lumen (5.2.6) (Laravel Components 5.2.*)**

Answer (score 11):

It's installed by default.

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->make('view')->make('welcome');
});
```

Make a file `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php` to see it works.

---

### UPDATE

In Lumen 5.5, you can do this:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->make('view')->make('welcome');
});
```

Comment: thanks @Krisan Alfa Timur, but I got a better way

```$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return view('welcome');
});```

Comment: Yes, it can. But accessing view via `$app->make('view')` is slightly faster than using `view` function.